# Pandas: dataframe is highly fragmented. this is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with 111 columns and 75k rows. I want to add 6 columns based on other columns' calculations:

```
df['col1_4'] = df['col1_1'] - df['col1_2'] - df['col1_3']
df['col2_4'] = df['col2_1'] - df['col2_2'] - df['col2_3']
df['col3_4'] = df['col3_1'] - df['col3_2'] - df['col3_3']
df['col4_4'] = df['col4_1'] - df['col4_2'] - df['col4_3']
df['col5_4'] = df['col5_1'] - df['col5_2'] - df['col5_3']
df['col6_4'] = df['col6_1'] - df['col6_2'] - df['col6_3']
```

I get the warning:

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`

First of all, should I be wary of a 'fragmented' data frame? what does it mean and will that cause problems using the data frame going forward? How does copying the data frame make it 'de-fragmented'?

I rewrote the same operations like this:

```
col1 = df['col1_1'] - df['col1_2'] - df['col1_3']
col2 = df['col2_1'] - df['col2_2'] - df['col2_3']
col3 = df['col3_1'] - df['col3_2'] - df['col3_3']
col4 = df['col4_1'] - df['col4_2'] - df['col4_3']
col5 = df['col5_1'] - df['col5_2'] - df['col5_3']
col6 = df['col6_1'] - df['col6_2'] - df['col6_3']

df = pd.concat([df, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6], axis=1])
```

and didn't get any warning. But I still don't understand the warning or why using this method helps. I've essentially just added one more step in between.

Comment: You should post a reproducible example. I created a 75000x111 sample and had no issues creating 6 new columns dependent on the existing columns: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((75000, 111))); df['a']=df[0]-df[1]-df[2]; df['b']=df[1]-df[2]-df[3]; df['c']=df[2]-df[3]-df[4]; df['d']=df[3]-df[4]-df[5]; df['e']=df[4]-df[5]-df[6]; df['f']=df[5]-df[6]-df[7]`

Comment: If I had to guess, the real issue is not from these 6 assignments but an earlier part of the code that created/manipulated the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to add a reproducible example tomorrow. The actual data is read from a MySQL table using pd.read_sql. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, there is nothing "wrong" with the way you did it originally, it is more a matter of performance.  The warning serves to tell you that there is a better way to do it.  As the notebook screenshot on this page" https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42477 demonstrates, using `pd.concat` can be 10x faster or more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing is, I'll need to perform the arithmetic operations anyways, so method 1 took less time actually. Not to mention that time is not really an issue for me. I was just worried that the first code 'damages' the data frame somehow. I'm not sure if there's a better method to use in my case.